# changing multiple filnenames

Tags: r, macos, terminal

I have a folder with multiple files with the name

> author - journal year - title.pdf
> e.g. "Hanahan Weinberg - Cell 2011 - Hallmarks of Cancer The Next Generation.pdf".

I want to change them all to

> year journal - author - title.pdf
> e.g. "2011 Cell - Hanahan Weinberg - Hallmarks of Cancer The Next Generation.pdf"

Is there a way to do this in Mac terminal or in R ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can rearrange the backreference after capturing them

```
sub("^(\\w+)\\s+-\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)(.*)", "\\3 \\2 - \\1\\4", str1)
#[1] "year journal - author - title.pdf"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "author - journal year - title.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

To rename files, use `rename` command line tool:

```
rename 's{ (.*?) \s*-\s* (.*?) \s*-\s* (.*) }{$2 - $1 - $3}x' *pdf
```

The regex uses modifier `/x` : Ignore whitespace and comments, for readability.
`(.*?) \s*-\s*` : any character, repeated 0 or more times, non-greedy (`*?` : minimal length match), followed by whitespace repeated 0 or more times, literal dash, and more whitespace repeated 0 or more times.

---

The command-line utility `rename` comes in many flavors. Most of them should work for this task. I used the [`rename`](https://github.com/ap/rename) version 1.601 by Aristotle Pagaltzis. To install `rename`, simply download its Perl script and place it into `$PATH`. Or install `rename` using `conda`, like so:

```
conda install rename
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
# Create example input file:
touch 'Doe - 2021 - Foo bar.pdf'

# Dry run - just print, do not rename anything:
rename -n 's{ (.*?) \s*-\s* (.*?) \s*-\s* (.*) }{$2 - $1 - $3}x' *pdf

# Actuall rename:
rename 's{ (.*?) \s*-\s* (.*?) \s*-\s* (.*) }{$2 - $1 - $3}x' *pdf
```